# Asymptotic decay for the wave equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the wave equation 
$$
y_{tt} = \Delta y - \epsilon y_t 
$$

on $\Omega\subset R^n$, with Dirichlet boundary conditions. 
 Where $\epsilon >0$.

Is it possible to find an  explicit value $\sigma=\sigma(\epsilon ) > 0$ such that the 
solution $(y,y_t)$ verifies the estimate

$$
\|(y,y_t)\| \le M e^{-\sigma t} $$

Comment: Even though this is too late, but maybe someone will be interested in the following paper which seems to answer the question in a different way than what @Igor Khavkine answer's suggestion. 
1. Liu K, Rao B, Zhang X (2002) Stabilization of the wave equations with potential and indefinite damping. Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications 269: 747–769.

Answer (score 5):

If you diagonalize the Laplacian with mode functions $f_i$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions on $\Omega$, $\Delta f_i = -k_i^2 f_i$, then a simple calculation shows that a solution of the form $f_i e^{-i\omega_i t}$ will have a frequency of the form
$$ \omega_i = \pm\frac{\sqrt{4k_i^2-\epsilon^2}}{2} - \frac{i\epsilon}{2} . $$
As you can see, the imaginary part of the frequency is always the same, so (modulo some technical details about expressing any solution in terms of mode functions) your decay constant is $\sigma = \epsilon/2$.

Comment: For the above analysis you need $\epsilon$ to be sufficiently small compared to the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian. Consider the case $\Omega = [0,\pi]\subset \mathbb{R}$, and $\epsilon = 4$ which is more than twice the first eigenvalue. One checks that $$ y(x,t) = e^{(-2 + \sqrt{3})t} \sin(x)$$ is a solution and decays strictly slower than $e^{-2t}$ ... See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping#Over-damping_.28.CE.B6_.3E_1.29 also for the classical harmonic oscillator analogue. 

Comment: Of course. I intuitively considered $\epsilon$ to be "sufficiently small".